# How to compare value of a dynamically created radio button

Tags: php

I am dynamically generating a set of radio buttons from MySQL. The buttons are creating and the variables assigned to them are populating as I did an echo print_r and it shows the array for the variable. I now want to compare the values generated from this and if the vale is "0" I want to insert a score and present a green check graphic and the word correct. If the value is "1" I want it to input different values for the score and present Incorrect and a red X graphic. Here is what I have so far (Everything populates dynamically both the question and the answers as radio buttons):

```
<?php
echo '<form id="frmQuestion" name="frmQuestion" method="post" action="QuizQuestion1.php">';

// Connect to the Database
require_once('mysqli_connect.php');

//create the query for the question
$q = "SELECT `Question` FROM tbl_Question WHERE QuestionID = 1";

//Create the query for the Answers
$q2 = "SELECT `Answer`,`AnswerStatusID`,`AnswerResponse` FROM tbl_Answer WHERE QuestionID = 1";

//Run the query
$r = mysqli_query($conn,$q);

//run the answer query
$r2 = mysqli_query($conn,$q2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div id="Question1"><p> ' . $row['Question'] . '</div></p>';
}

//Declare the variables as a array
$AnswerResponse = array();
$AnswerStatusID = array();

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    echo '<div id="Question1"><input name="q1" type="radio" value="'.$AnswerStatusID.'"/>' . $row2['Answer'] . '</div><br/>';

    //Assign the AnswerStatusID to a var
    $AnswerStatusID[] = $row2['AnswerStatusID'];

    //Assign the AnswerResponse to a var
    $AnswerResponse[] = $row2['AnswerResponse'];
}

//Create the submit button 
echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Answer" name="submit"/>';
echo '</form>';

//Logic for correct or incorrect answers
if (isset($_POST['q1']) && ($_POST['q1'] == '0'))
{
    //create the query for the score
    $q3 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Score (`Score`,`QuestionID`) VALUES ('100%','1')";   

    //Run the query 
    $r = @mysqli_query ($conn,$q3);

    if($r){

        //Confirm message data was entered with a correct response and a graphic
        echo '<h1>Correct!!</h1><img src="/images/green_Check_Low.jpg" alt="Green Check"/>';
        echo '<a href="QuizQuestion2.php">Click here for the next question</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        //there was an error
        echo'<h1>System error</h1>';

        //Debugging message
        echo'<p>' . mysqli_error($conn) . '<br/><br/>Query:' . $q3 . '</p>';

    }//End of nested IF
}
else{
    //create the query for the score
    $q4 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Score (`Score`,`QuestionID`) VALUES ('0%','1')"; 

    //Run the query 
    $r2 = @mysqli_query ($conn,$q3);

    if($r2){

        //Confirm message data was entered with a correct response and a graphic
        echo '<h1>Incorrect!!</h1><img src="/images/red_X_Low.jpg" alt="Red X"/>';
        echo '<a href="QuizQuestion2.php">Click here for the next question</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        //there was an error
        echo'<h1>System error</h1>';

        //Debugging message
        echo'<p>' . mysqli_error($conn) . '<br/><br/>Query:' . $q3 . '</p>';

    }//End of nested IF

}

//Free up the results for the Question query
mysqli_free_result($r);

//Free up the results from the Answer query
mysqli_free_result($r2);

//close the DB connection
mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
```

Comment: dont post complete code. post only relevant code. BTW there is no checkbox in given code

Comment: There's a radiobutton `<input name="q1" type="radio"...`, I think that's what he's referring to.

Comment: yes it is a radiobutton and all the code posted is relevent as you need to see where the buttons are populated and created in my opinion to be able to see what it is I am asking

Comment: the AnswerStatusID is in a table and is "0" for correct or a "1" for the incorrect answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer and work as intended. Thanks for everyones input.

```
//Declare the variables as a array
$AnswerResponse = array();
$AnswerStatusID = array();

while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
echo '<div id="Question1"><input name="q1" type="radio" value="'.$row2['AnswerStatusID'].'"/>' . $row2['Answer'] . '</div><br/>';

//Assign the AnswerStatusID to a var
$AnswerStatusID[] = $row2['AnswerStatusID'];

//Assign the AnswerResponse to a var
$AnswerResponse[] = $row2['AnswerResponse'];
}




//Create the submit button 
 echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit Answer" name="submit"/>';
echo '<input type="hidden"name="submitted"value="TRUE"/>';
echo '</form>';



if($_POST['submitted']) { 

//Logic for correct or incorrect answers
if (isset($_POST['q1']) && ($_POST['q1'] == '0'))
{
//create the query for the score
$q3 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Score (`Score`,`QuestionID`) VALUES ('100%','1')";   

//Run the query 
$r3 = @mysqli_query ($conn,$q3);

//Confirm message data was entered with a correct response and a graphic
echo '<h1>Correct!!</h1><img src="/images/green_Check_Low.jpg" alt="Green Check"/>';
echo '<a href="QuizQuestion2.php">Click here for the next question</a>';


}       
else{
//create the query for the score
$q4 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Score (`Score`,`QuestionID`) VALUES ('0%','1')"; 

//Run the query 
$r4 = @mysqli_query ($conn,$q4);

//Confirm message data was entered with a correct response and a graphic
echo '<h1>Incorrect!!</h1><img src="/images/red_X_Low.jpg" alt="Red X"/><br/>';
echo '<a href="QuizQuestion1.php">Click here to try again</a>';

}

}
```